# .append to a non DOM element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

I'm trying to append to a non DOM element (Pagiantion added for a slideshow).

My code is:

```
$("#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a").on("click", function (event) {
    alert('append');
});
```

which does not give me an alert. As `on` is replacing `live`, I'm wondering why this doesn't work?

**UPDATE** The comment by [adeno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) helped, and my code is now :

```
$(document).on("ready", "#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a", function (event) {
    $("#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a").prepend("Image");
    $("#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a").append(" of 30");
});
```

which doesn't work, how do I attach an event that recgonises when it is the element is loaded?

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a", function(event){...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: I don't see what your question has to do with appending, nor why you're calling this a "non DOM element".

Comment: Im just using the click function and alert to test .on, by non DOM element i mean it doesnt exist unti the document is ready

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a"`, function(event){ } worked thanks, so now my code is `$(document).on("ready", "#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a", function(event){
    $("#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a").prepend("Image ");
    $("#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a").append(" of 30");
});`

Which doesnt work, how do i attach an event that recgonises when it is the element is loaded?

Comment: @user3050844 your question is very poor. create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You must bind the event to the parent element, then select the target element using the `selector` argument. You can find more information about `.on()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('#slides2').on('click', '.slidesjs-pagination-item a', function(e) {
    alert('append');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#slides2").on("click", ".slidesjs-pagination-item a", function(event){
    alert('append');
});
```

Though it's hard to tell without seeing any HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Two potential pointers:

1. Does the line below return a number > 0? If not your selector is wrong.

   `alert($("#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a").length)`
2. You mention that you trying to append to a non DOM element. Is the element you select attached to the DOM at all? If not: you cannot click on a non DOM node.

Comment: .slidesjs-pagination-item a isnt a DOM element, its added by a js file

Answer (score 0):

$("#blah") wont work if the element is not in the DOM.
I guess your template is in parameter, so do this:

```
$("#blah", myTemplate).click(...
```